# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: tracker-db.users index: username_1 dup key: { username: null }"

Tags: node.js, mongoose, backend

A bunch of similar questions answered before but none of them seem to fix my problem. No problem in adding the first user. However, the username doesn't display the records and gives error on adding the second user.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
        },
        gender: String,
        age: Number
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

[The error that I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpamq.png)

[The record on adding first user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdp1e.png)

Comment: Please check whether the `user` document that you are saving has a not null `username`. I think during the first and second time username is passed as null to the database.

Comment: Yes, thats what is happening, but how do I change that? Any suggestions

Comment: Can you add the code that is actually using the model to save the user? It looks like it is not using the `required: true`, if it is saving without a username

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply **drop the collection** and make the request again . This should work just fine.

Comment: do you know why this error happens? also your solution worked!!

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the collection and recreating the collection in mongodb worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In Robo3T I had to look up my collections indexes, and manually delete the username index.

Answer (score 2):

add a username to your schema, i had the same problem and i did this

function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
console.log(profile);
User.findOrCreate({ username: profile.displayName, googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
return cb(err, user);
});
i simply added a username in my findorcreate function so that it does not show username null

Answer (score 1):

Your collection has a extra index named username_1 which is causing this error. When you already have 1 document in your collection with that parameter (username_1) as null, mongodb does not allow to add one more document after that with the same paramter as null (which you are doing without knowing).

**How to fix it?**
You need to delete the index named username_1 from your collection. If you are using MongoDBCompass, go to Indexes and delete the index named username_1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, I wish it will be helpful.

Creating a new Database in MongoDB server and saving the data in that new location, worked for me :-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not in this module you presented here.

We need to see your code from **your.js file** assuming you are using **express** and **body-parser** to make all this work. I think and i made a little trial of your app and i can tell that your REQ POST using **POSTMAN** is **incorrect**. WHY ? Because you are sending a POST REQ to

```
   http://localhost:3000/users/add

   and you are setting PARAMS with username: randomguy
   and that's why you're getting that error from MongoDB 
   {username: null}.
```

To fix this issue in **POSTMAN** you must leave **PARAMS EMPTY** (REMOVE ALL KEY/VALUE FIELDS) and instead make the POST request including **KEY/VALUE in BODY Field**:

```
   username: randomGuy
```

In my case i'm using body-parser like this:

```
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

and in POSTMAN in BODY select the radiobutton x-www-form-urlencoded

/*PARAMS is used for GET req*/

[POSTMAN POST REQ TO local MongoDB with BODY KEY/VALUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN20O.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **@alps** solved my issue here is copy paste for beginners:
add `username: profile.displayName` in my `User.findorcreate` function
for reference:

**For Google**:

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log(profile);
    User.findOrCreate({ username: profile.displayName, googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) { 
     return cb(err, user) 
    });
}
```

**For Facebook:**

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log(profile);
    User.findOrCreate({ username: profile.displayName, facebookId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the indexes on database once  and try again, I am sure this will work

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you set the username to be unique in your model and must have likely created the initial document in your collection.

To solve the problem, navigate to the index in your collection and delete the username.

It should work

[image: db collection index]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MongoDB. Delete your database using Mongo Compass or using terminal.. Thats works for me.