# Why is MongoDB not saving my user (issues with async/await?) - Express, mongoDB, Oauth

Tags: mongodb, express, oauth

I'm using Oauth to allow my users to sign in with their google account. I have successfully created a function which checks if the email is verified and then, depending on if the user is already saved in the data base, just send back the user - or if the user doesn't exsist create a new user.

My console displays the message "Email is verified" and "User not found" so I know it makes it to that part of the code - but it doesn't proceed to create a new user. My suspicions is that is has to do with the async await and that things are perhaps happening in the wrong order. Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

```
app.post("/googlelogin", (req, res) => {
  const { tokenId } = req.body

  client.verifyIdToken({
    idToken: tokenId, 
    audience: 'XXXX' // removed for demo
  })
    .then(async (response) => {
      const { email_verified, name, email } = response.payload
      console.log(response.payload)

      if (email_verified) {
        console.log('email is verified')

        try {
          const user = await User.findOne({ name, email })
            if (user) {
              console.log('User found!')
              return res.json({
                success: true,
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                token: user.token,
                userID: user._id
              })
            } else {
              console.log('User not found!')
              let newUser = await new User({
                name, 
                email
              }).save()

              return res.json({
                success: true,
                name: newUser.name,
                email: newUser.email,
                token: newUser.token,
                userID: newUser._id
              })
            }
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).json({
              success: false,
              message: "Something went wrong",
              error
            })
        }
      } else {
          return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            error: "Email not verified",
          })
      }

  })
})
```

Comment: write your async function in the then block separately and then wait for it .

Comment: What JSON response are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

Found this thread and followed the tip to drop my collection and after this it worked!

[MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: tracker-db.users index: username_1 dup key: { username: null }"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63828277/mongoerror-e11000-duplicate-key-error-collection-tracker-db-users-index-usern)